# Representing a skill level

Tags: usability, mobile, visual-design, skills

Can anybody advise a good ux design for representing a skill level (novice, competent, proficient, expert) for a professional service (for example, doctor, lawyer, interpreter and etc.) in a marketplace app. And how it can be made more useful for a customer (maybe add some discription because the customer is not aware of difference of the levels)?

Some clarification....

In all fields of man's activity a person passes through skill acquisition - A JOURNEY FROM NOVICE TO EXPERT - begins as a novice...and ends as an expert (if he is lucky). Let's take a dentist. At first, he is the novice and just learns at university…but he can do some simple work - for example, teeth cleaning. Then he can drill and then make a solution to fill a tooth. So at first he gains knowledge and some experience.  But as he is getting mature his knowledge and skills are getting better and better. Hence, his experience consists of tasks (or what he can do) and skill level of each task (or how good he is at). But at each stage of his skill journey he is able to provide his service...even he is a novice doctor he can find his patient or a patient can find him.

So how can we represent these skill levels (novice, competent, proficient and expert) in order to help (1) a customer to understand what this level means to make the right choice (with regard to price/quality) and (2) a service provider to differentiate himself (with regard to price/quality)?

Comment: I think you have some fundamental issues here before you even get to UX: 1) If people are selling their services, you aren't going to get an honest self-assessment of skill level, but if not self-assessment, then how is this measured?  2) Who would want to be branded as a "novice" doctor or buy services from a novice doctor?  This sort of designation would prevent participation in your marketplace.

Comment: Yes, you are partly right. But let me parafrase….

Comment: I take it that you're looking to create a flow chart. Perhaps using a Venn diagram showing the skills involved (this has been numerous times) would  be your best bet.